# Sending a file (.PDF) trough whatsapp using HREF only

Tags: whatsapp

I'm trying to use the HREF to send a PDF file via whatsapp through my application.
Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Not possible directly but you can use whatsapp's share URI scheme to link the PDF from an external server: `href="whatsapp://send?text=PDF%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fyourserver.com/doc.pdf"` which results in `"PDF: http://yourserver.com/doc.pdf"`

Comment: Well, that's one way to send yeah.
Thank you @NullDev!